# Retrieve rows with highest salary per month and year

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to do this but I don't know as. I have this table.

```
SSN | SALARY  |   MONTH YEAR
1234   1881,33     01     2008
8762   2578        01     2008
8726   2183,6475   01     2008
2321   1745,8525   01     2008
3123   1639,2      01     2008
1934   2572        01     2008
```

Is it possible to select from months of all years the person that has the bigger salary? In this case January 2008 was 8762.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY year_month
                             ORDER BY money DESC ) AS rn
  FROM   (
    SELECT A.ssn,
           SUM(B.WAGE)- SUM(B.SALARY/(8*20)) AS money,
           TRUNC( rep_date, 'MM' ) AS year_month
    FROM   REP_LINES A 
           INNER JOIN COSTS B
           ON (    A.JOB=B.CAT_NUM
               and B.YEAR = EXTRACT( YEAR FROM A.REP_DATE ) )
    GROUP BY A.ssn,
           TRUNC( rep_date, 'MM' )
  ) t
)
WHERE  rn = 1;
```

Comment: What is t.? I cant use it

Answer (score 1):

You can use `keep`:

```
select year, month, max(salary) as salary,
       max(ssn) over (dense_rank first order by salary desc) as max_ssn
from (select to_char(l.rep_date, 'YYYY') as year, to_char(l.rep_date, 'MM') as month,
             l.SSN, (SUM(c.WAGE)- SUM(c.SALARY/(8*20))) as salary 
      from rep_lines l join
           costs c
           on l.job = c.cat_num and
              to_char(c.year) = to_char(l.rep_date, 'YYYY')
     )
group by year, month
order by year, month;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
SELECT 
  MONTH
  , YEAR
  , FIRST_VALUE(SALARY) OVER (PARTITION BY MONTH,YEAR ORDER BY SALARY DESC)
  , FIRST_VALUE(SSN) OVER (PARTITION BY MONTH,YEAR ORDER BY SALARY DESC)
FROM your_table;
```